# Writing text to a textbox's text property in a WINFORM

Tags: c#, winforms

New to WinForms but not ASP.NET or C#. Trying to make client/server app. Successfully received data from client on server but having troubles displaying it on server program winform. Codes are:

Server App code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace Server_App
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1234); //configure host
            TcpListenerEx listener = new TcpListenerEx(ep); //set host to listen
            if (!listener.Active)
            {
                listener.Start();
            }
            while (true)
            {
                const int byteSize = 1024 * 1024;
                byte[] message = new byte[byteSize];
                var s = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                s.GetStream().Read(message, 0, byteSize); //obtaining network stream and receiving data through .Read()
                message = cleanMessage(message);                
                string g = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);
                addMessage(g);    
            }
        }

        private void addMessage(string m)
        {
                this.textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + m;
        }

        private byte[] cleanMessage(byte[] rawMessageByte)
        {
            byte[] cleanMessage = rawMessageByte.Where(b => b != 0).ToArray();
            return cleanMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Client App code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClientApp
{
    public partial class ClientApp : Form
    {
        public ClientApp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtFromClient.Text);             
            using (var client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234))//make connection with the host
            {
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();/*obtain network stream*/                
                stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtFromClient.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is happening as planned except for displaying received data on server program's Form1's textbox. On debugging, I confirmed the correct value received in variable `m` of line `this.textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + m;`. Only problem is that this value cannot be displayed and hence seen on the Form1 of server program.

Comment: Does your textBox support multiline?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre `Multiline` is set to 'true' for `textBox1` on `Form1` of server app code. Yes.

Comment: Your click handler receives messages in a `while(true)` loop. It won't ever exit then controls won't ever have a chance to refresh (and application will hang). Move it to a `BackgroundWorker`. Another _minor_ thing: you do not need to call both `Dispose()` and `Close()` and it may be simplified with `using`. I'm sure there are other questions about same issue (to close this like dupe) but can't find it now

Comment: try use textBox1.AppendText(textBox1.Text  + Environment.NewLine+" >> "+m);

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti `while(true)` exists forever. its an infinite loop.

Comment: @RehanKhan Exactly and that's the problem! `button1_Click` won't ever exit and your form won't ever process any other Windows message. It won't paint controls, handle user input and it will hang. Oh, final note: you allocate a buffer for message but it's unused because you assign the buffer returned by `GetBytes()`. Compiler may elide the first allocation but it's still useless

Comment: @mww please don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I see.

Comment: To see the difference put (temporary!!!) `Application.DoEvents()` inside your loop. Application will start to work as expected. Then remove it immediately and move code from `while(true)` loop into a `BackgroundWorker` and it will work well

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, I've made changes to the code for the message buffer and `using` part. Meanwhile, I'm working on encapsulating `backgroundworker` process, can you please recheck it and confirm if that's what you meant for. Thanks.

Comment: One step! Now note that you're converting `message` back/to `string`/`byte[]`. It's a waste and (worse) it makes your code more complicate. `cleanMessage` may directly work with `byte[]` (it's even easier because stream is UTF8). `NetworkStream` is now handled correctly: no need to close it IF you close the container `TcpListener`, enclose that declaration inside something like `using (var listener = new TcpListenerEx(ep)) { /* ... */ }`. Do the same for client too, you're leaking reasources. You may consider an asynchronous approach also for client, network operations may have big latency

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti while doing `using (var listener = new TcpListenerEx(ep)) { /* ... */ }` its complaining that 'TcpListenerEx: type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertiable to 'System.IDisposable'.

Comment: Hmpf sorry, it's `TcpClient` to implement `IDisposable`!

Comment: Do it also for `listener.AcceptTcpClient()`. `b != '\0'` may simply be `b != 0`. If buffer is huge it may be convenient to do not create a copy but _shift back_ by one all the elements after each `0` (and to use the other overload of `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` which accepts an end index).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti did it for `listener.AcceptTcpClient()` and `b !=0` and posted an answer below with background worker implemented. Please review. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With the help and guidance from @AdrianoRepetti, solution to the given problem was furnished through the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;

namespace Server_App
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1234); //configure host
            if(!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(ep); //called to start a process on the worker thread and send argument (listener) to our workerprocess.
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            IPEndPoint ep = e.Argument as IPEndPoint;
            TcpListenerEx listener = new TcpListenerEx(ep);
            if (!listener.Active)
            {
                listener.Start();
            }
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    const int byteSize = 1024 * 1024;
                    byte[] message = new byte[byteSize];
                    using (var s = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
                    {
                        s.GetStream().Read(message, 0, byteSize);//obtaining network stream and receiving data through .Read()
                        message = cleanMessage(message);
                        string g = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, g);
                    }                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                     backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    listener.Stop();
                }
            }            
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + ">> " + e.UserState);
        }

        private byte[] cleanMessage(byte[] rawMessageByte)
        {
            byte[] cleanMessage = rawMessageByte.Where(b => b != 0).ToArray();
            return cleanMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just few minor things: I'd put listener.Stop() inside a finally{} block (because background thread will be interrupted when form is disposed). Check if backgroundWorker is already working before starting (backgroundWorker.IsBusy property).

Comment: :) Do not add an empty catch block, it'll _hide_ errors. Just try {} finally {}

Comment: Empty catch block has now been blessed with a line of code.

Comment: How to now convert this app to listen to Asynchronous requests @AdrianoRepetti from here?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti you there mate?